# Proving that $\sin(x+y)$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, uniform-continuity

How may I prove that both are uniformly continuous?:

1. $f(x,y)=\sin(x+y)$
   for 1, I said, let $\epsilon > 0$ if $d((x,y),(u,v))<\lambda$:

$|f(x,y)-f(u,v)|<|f(x,y)|+|f(u,v)|=|\sin(x+y)|+|\sin(u,v)|<|x+y|+|u+v|$

But how may I continue from here?

Comment: Your line beginning with 1. is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}|\sin(x+y)-\sin(u+v)|&\leqslant|\sin(x+y)-\sin(x+v)|+|\sin(x+v)-\sin(u+v)|\\&\leqslant|y-v|+|x-u|.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why $sin(+)−sin(+) < |y-v|$ we know that $|sin|(x)<|x|$

Comment: $|\sin(x+y)-\sin(x+v)|\leqslant|(x+y)-(x+v)|=|y-v|$

Comment: Edit: I can't continue from here. How this: ((,),(,))<  => $(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2<^2$ may be helpful in your case?

Comment: Now you use the fact that$$|x-u|+|y-v|\leqslant\sqrt2\lVert(x,y)-(u,v)\rVert.$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, you can take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt2}$.